# Ошибка Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.1.0 при сборке теста

Tags: java, исключения, maven, тестирование, автоматизация

Коллеги! Помогите пожалуйста начинающему автотестировщику )

Три недели рою и-нет. Перепробовал все советы по похожим пролемам.
Собрал тест с использованием maven, junit5, selenium, allure. Кнопкой run в IntelliJ IDEA тест успешно запускается, но при запуске из командной строки (что требуется для дальнейшего запуска из GitLab CI)  терминал сообщает о следующей ошибке.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.surefire.api.testset.TestSetFailedException
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.1.0:test (default-test) on project testNeo: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.1.0:test failed: A required 
class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.1.0:test: org/apache/maven/surefire/api/testset/TestSetFailedException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.1.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/3.1.0/maven-surefire-plugin-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-surefire-provider/1.3.2/junit-platform-surefire-provider-1.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.0.0/apiguardian-api-1.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-launcher/1.3.2/junit-platform-launcher-1.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-engine/1.3.2/junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-commons/1.3.2/junit-platform-commons-1.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/opentest4j/opentest4j/1.1.1/opentest4j-1.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.22.0/surefire-api-2.22.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-logger-api/2.22.0/surefire-logger-api-2.22.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/common-java5/2.22.0/common-java5-2.22.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.20/aspectjweaver-1.9.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/3.1.0/maven-surefire-common-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-extensions-api/3.1.0/surefire-extensions-api-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/3.1.0/surefire-booter-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-extensions-spi/3.1.0/surefire-extensions-spi-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/3.1.1/maven-common-artifact-filters-3.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.11.0/commons-io-2.11.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-java/1.1.2/plexus-java-1.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.4/asm-9.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0.3/qdox-2.0.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-shared-utils/3.1.0/surefire-shared-utils-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : org.apache.maven.surefire.api.testset.TestSetFailedException
```

Использую следующий POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>testNeo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>testNeo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version> 3.3.1 </version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version> 3.1.0 </version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/junit5.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>TestSetFailedException</exclude>
          </excludes>
          <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
          <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
          <argLine>
-javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
          </argLine>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <allure.results.directory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
          <systemProperties>
            <property>
              <name>junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled</name>
              <value>true</value>
            </property>
            <property>
              <name>allure.results.directory</name>
              <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
            </property>
          </systemProperties>
          <properties>
            <java.version>8</java.version>
            <property>
              <name>listener</name>
              <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener</value>
            </property>
            <property>
              <name>allure.results.directory</name>
              <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
            </property>
          </properties>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version> 1.3.2</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
        <version> 2.12.0 </version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
     <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <junit-platform-surefire-provider.version>1.3.2</junit-platform-surefire-provider.version>
    <aspectj.version> 1.9.20 </aspectj.version>
    <allure-junit5.version>2.6.0</allure-junit5.version>
  </properties>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Central</name>
      <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
      <version> 1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
      <version> 2.24.0 </version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version> 5.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version> 4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version> 3.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version> 3.3.1 </version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version> 3.1.0 </version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
      <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
      <version> 5.5.3 </version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
      <version> 4.1.100.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Не могу понять что не так с Surefure и почему отсутствует необходимый класс TestSetFailedException. Он ведь входит в пакет apachi-maven-surefire плагин?

Comment: попробуйте сменить SDK на другую. Мне помогло при такой ошибке(с 17-ой на 15-ю)